# Node JS library OneDrive API

Tags: node.js, npm, onedrive

I found a Node JS client https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-onedrive-unofficial. Which has limited features included.
Is there any official Node JS library/client available for OneDrive API?

Answer (score 1):

Iam using this you can try this below link

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript